# Have content size to remaining available space, but show scrollbar on div if required

Tags: javascript, html, css

This feels like something which should be achievable, but I can't find the right combination of properties that does what I need.

I have a layout that has the following:

- A title bar along the top that should always be visible
- A menu on the left which is opened/closed with a button in the title bar
- The remaining space (to the right of menu, below title bar) is filled by whatever content is displayed (based on what menu item the user clicks, a different page/content is put in this div)

The key thing I want is that when the content needs more space, the scrollbars should be for scrolling the stuff inside `page-container`, not the the whole page (i.e. title bar and menu should appear fixed in place).

Additionally, in the page content there's a `details-panel` div which I want to always be visible, and it should cause the content above it (in this case `page-content`) to shrink to accommodate this.

Below is a code snippet which shows where I've got to; note that when the view is smaller than the content, the scrollbars are scrolling the whole page (including title bar and menu items), as well the `detail-panel` not being kept in the view.

[Here is a codepen of the same.](https://codepen.io/will_scc/pen/LYvYadd)

```js
document.getElementById('menu-toggle').addEventListener('click', function () {
 document.getElementById('menu').classList.toggle('closed');
        
document.getElementById('menu-toggle').classList.toggle('closed');
    });
```

```css
html, body {
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#parent-container {
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#title-bar {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
}

#menu-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2em;
    user-select: none;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}

#menu.closed {
    max-width: 0;
    transition: max-width 0.3s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#menu-toggle.closed {
    transform: rotate(0);
    transition: transform .3s ease-in;
}

.top-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#menu {
    background-color: grey;
    max-width: 200px; /* just an arbitrary bigger-than-needed value to allow transition */
    transition: max-width 0.3s ease-in;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#content {
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.page-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: pink;
}

.page-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.detail-panel {
    background: teal;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-container">

    <div id="title-bar">
        <h1 id="menu-toggle">+</h1>
        <h1>The Title</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="top-container">
        <div id="menu">
          <ul>
            <li>Menu Item 1</li>
            <li>Menu Item 2</li>
            <li>Menu Item 3</li>
            <li>Menu Item 4</li>
            <li>Menu Item 5</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <div class="page-container">
              The stuff in within page-container could change to anything based on whichever menu item the user selects, so everything "above" this must be fairly generic, and not dependent on the content within.
              </br></br>
      
              <div class="page-content">
                
                  This should show a scrollbar (horizontal and vertical) if required.
                
                </br></br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis. Laoreet sit amet cursus sit. Diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse. Enim eu turpis egestas pretium. Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit. Non consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis.

Vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at. Aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus. Tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed lectus. Vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus. Nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium. Vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. A scelerisque purus semper eget duis at tellus at. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis. Lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium. Maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet.

Ornare arcu odio ut sem. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna. Facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet. Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies. Risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum. Laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et. Gravida quis blandit turpis cursus.

Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc. Nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget. Viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac. Nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit. Enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper. Magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris. Arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. At augue eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam. Semper viverra nam libero justo.

Eu consequat ac felis donec. Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque. Phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Tortor at auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id. Nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis. Scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc. Pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus. Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac odio tempor. Feugiat in ante metus dictum at tempor commodo. Purus in mollis nunc sed id.
              </div>

              <div class="detail-panel">
                  This should always be displayed at the bottom of the view.
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I know what height that should be, given the user can resize the window?

Comment: Have I not done that with `#parent-container { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's plenty of ways to do it, but for this example I opted to use `grid` to create the layout. The `div.detail-panel` will expand as needed and `div.page-content` will always become a scroll container whenever content overflows.

I noticed that you have an animated menu so I added the animation effect on `div.container`

```js
const toggle = document.getElementById('menuToggle');

toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.container').classList.toggle('show-menu');
})

const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu li');
const pageContent = document.querySelector('.page-content');
menuItems.forEach((li) => {
  li.addEventListener('click', () => {
    pageContent.textContent = data[li.dataset.id];
  })
})

const data = {
  1: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis. Laoreet sit amet cursus sit. Diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse. Enim eu turpis egestas pretium. Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit. Non consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis.

        Vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at. Aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus. Tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed lectus. Vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus. Nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium. Vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. A scelerisque purus semper eget duis at tellus at. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis. Lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium. Maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet.

        Ornare arcu odio ut sem. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna. Facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet. Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies. Risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum. Laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et. Gravida quis blandit turpis cursus.

        Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc. Nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget. Viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac. Nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit. Enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper. Magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris. Arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. At augue eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam. Semper viverra nam libero justo.

        Eu consequat ac felis donec. Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque. Phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Tortor at auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id. Nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis. Scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc. Pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus. Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac odio tempor. Feugiat in ante metus dictum at tempor commodo. Purus in mollis nunc sed id.`,
  2: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis. Laoreet sit amet cursus sit. Diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse. Enim eu turpis egestas pretium. Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit. Non consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis.',
  3: 'Vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at. Aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus. Tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur. Sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed lectus. Vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus. Nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium. Vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est. Bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. A scelerisque purus semper eget duis at tellus at. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis. Lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo. Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium. Maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet',
  4: 'Ornare arcu odio ut sem. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna. Facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit amet. Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies. Risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum. Laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et. Gravida quis blandit turpis cursus.',
  5: 'Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc. Nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget. Viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac. Nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit. Enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper. Magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris. Arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. At augue eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet. Vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam. Semper viverra nam libero justo.',
  6: 'Eu consequat ac felis donec. Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque. Phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Tortor at auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id. Nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis. Scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc. Pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus. Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac odio tempor. Feugiat in ante metus dictum at tempor commodo. Purus in mollis nunc sed id.'
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "title title" "menu content" "menu content" "menu detail";
  transition: 300ms;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: 130px 1fr;
  height: 100%;
  &.show-menu {
    grid-template-columns: 0 1fr;
  }
}

.page-content {
  grid-area: content;
  background: green;
  overflow: auto;
}

.detail-panel {
  grid-area: detail;
  background: turquoise;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  background: grey;
}

.title-bar {
  grid-area: title;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  background: blue;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}


/* CSS RESET */


/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="title-bar">
    <button id="menuToggle">
            X
        </button>
    <h1>
      The Title
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li data-id="1">Menu Item 1</li>
      <li data-id="2">Menu Item 2</li>
      <li data-id="3">Menu Item 3</li>
      <li data-id="4">Menu Item 4</li>
      <li data-id="5">Menu Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="page-content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut. Tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis. Laoreet sit amet cursus
    sit. Diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse. Enim eu turpis egestas pretium. Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque. Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper
    sit. Non consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis. Vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at. Aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus. Tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa. Urna id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur. Sem viverra
    aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras. Sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed lectus. Vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus. Nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium. Vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est. Bibendum at
    varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. A scelerisque purus semper eget duis at tellus at. Venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis. Lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit. Ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo.
    Tempor nec feugiat nisl pretium. Maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet. Ornare arcu odio ut sem. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna. Facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras. Enim diam vulputate ut pharetra sit
    amet. Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies. Risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum. Laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl. Quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam
    sem et. Gravida quis blandit turpis cursus. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc. Nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget. Viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac. Nibh praesent tristique
    magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit. Enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper.
    Magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris. Arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit. At augue eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Velit egestas dui id ornare arcu odio ut. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet.
    Vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam. Semper viverra nam libero justo. Eu consequat ac felis donec. Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque
    egestas congue. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque. Phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Tortor at auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam. Turpis cursus in hac habitasse
    platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id. Nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl. Cras adipiscing enim eu turpis. Scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc. Pulvinar proin gravida
    hendrerit lectus. Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac odio tempor. Feugiat in ante metus dictum at tempor commodo. Purus in mollis nunc sed id.
  </div>

  <div class="detail-panel">
    detail
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it does exactly what I was trying to achieve. I think I got so hooked up on doing it with flex boxes I didn't consider using something else.  I'll have a go at implementing it in my project and mark as answer shortly.